# Is there a way to get document and window properties in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to get document and window properties in the chrome developer toolbox?

I don't see it in the element tab of the developer toolbox. This would be really handy when troubleshooting jquery.offset problems

While were at it we might as well discuss this in firefox 4+

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try typing in the console:

```
console.dir(window) //just "window" would work too
console.dir(document)
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can just type in the devtools console (F12 on Windows or Cmd+Alt+ on Mac):

```
window // logs the window object
document // logs the document object
```