# Which format is better for list in JSON API design, flat array or nested object?

Tags: json, api, data-structures, api-design, requirements

For list API, such as `Users`, I find that there are two common formats. Arrays:

```
// flat array
[
  {
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

[GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users), [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-list)  and [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search) use this format

VS Objects:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

[Parse](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users-querying) and [Slack](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) and [instagram](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search) use this format.

Which one is better? How to compare these two formats?

Comment: I would argue that the second method is more extensible. It is backwards compatible in the event that you'd like to, for example, include some metadata in the object under another member name. The first method would be guaranteed require a breaking change in the event that you wanted to add to the schema.

Comment: Make sense. So I just don't understand why GitHub, Heroku and Twitter use the first method.

Answer (score 1):

Array-oriented data has the following advantages:

- Client-side JavaScript has more methods for arrays than objects
- No need for root node to simulate a tree structure for a tabular structure

and disadvantages:

- No namespacing since indexes are numeric
- `JSON.parse` fails in client-side JavaScript

Key/Value-oriented data has the following advantages:

- `JSON.parse` works in client-side JavaScript
- Namespacing makes duplicate values easier to disambiguate
- `JSON.stringify` works to make [simple transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288820/what-are-the-differences-between-using-json-arrays-vs-json-objects/23437276#23437276) easier compared to array methods

and disadvantages:

- It can be [hard to iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977889/is-it-possible-to-show-only-user-defined-functions-properties-in-google-chrome/18452999#18452999) nested hierarchies without a library in client-side code
- `JSON.parse` in client-side code [removes duplicate key names on the same level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618767/eliminate-duplicates-in-array-jsoniq/19821769#19821769)

**References**

- [Want to return and array from the Restful Web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169591/want-to-return-and-array-from-the-restful-web-services)
- [Read local file text (tab separated values) with d3 or ajax cause syntax error in firefox development console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226719/read-local-file-text-tab-separated-values-with-d3-or-ajax-cause-syntax-error-i)
- [Query JSON/XML/CSV using SQL | Joe Conley](http://www.josephpconley.com/2014/05/13/datacombinator-query-engine.html)